# Mathematica freezes when pressing save as

Tags: crash, save

When I try to save a notebook, Mathematica freezes (https://youtu.be/U-8xsjrOmt0).

If I wait for around 2 minutes the save menu eventually shows up.

If I want to just save existing saved nb., there's no problem. It happens with **save as** and save for unsaved nbs.

I've never had the same problem. I also didn' t change anything on my os (Windows 11) or Mathematica (13) settings before this started to happen.

After that, I also restarted my PC and nothing changed.

Is there an easy fix for this?

Comment: Can you monitor the CPU and check if there are other processes that interfere? This is the only thing that comes to mind

Comment: No such proceses. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe it's trying to access a network location to save to and the location is not available to you on this computer, but you have to wait until something times out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled mathematica and the things went back to normal.
Then I opened the notebook that I had opened, when the problem first started, and the problem was back again.
Reinstalled again and it was back to normal.

Conclusion: probably something strange on that specific notebook file. I copied content to another notebook, which then didn' t cause problems.

Maybe it was because i edited that notebook on 2 different PCs with different Mathematica versions.

Anyway it's back to normal now.